# Python Loop that gets html tags returning empty list instead of tags

Tags: python, html, list, if-statement, for-loop

So I'm trying to make a function that will go through a list of html tags in a list as characters and return the tags. An example would be it would go through a list like below

['<', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', '>', '<', 'h', 'e', 'a', 'd', '>', '<', 'm', 'e', 't', 'a', '>']

and return a list like this

[ 'html', 'head', 'meta' ]

However when I run the function below it returns an empty list []

```
def getTag(htmlList):
    tagList=[]
    for iterate, character in enumerate(htmlList):
        tagAppend = ''
        if character=='<':
            for index, word in enumerate(htmlList):
                if index>iterate:
                    if character=='>':
                        tagList.append(tagAppend)
                        break
                    tagAppend += character

    return tagList
```

The program seem make sense to me? It creates an empty list (tagList) then it iterates through the list(htmlList) like the first list I posted.

When iterating if it comes across a '<' it then adds all characters above the index where it found the '<' to a string called tagAppend. It then stops when it reaches a '>' which ends the tag. The tagAppend is then added to the tagList. It then clears tagList and redoes to the loop.

Answer (score 1):

That looks too complicated. Instead, join the list into a string, remove the opening angle brackets, and split on the closing angle brackets, remembering to discard the empty strings:

```
def get_tag(l):
    return [item for item in ''.join(l).replace('<','').split('>') if item]
```

Result:

```
>>> l = ['<', 'h', 't', 'm', 'l', '>', '<', 'h', 'e', 'a', 'd', '>', '<', 'm', 'e', 't', 'a', '>']
>>> get_tag(l)
['html', 'head', 'meta']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is just an exercise for the sake of learning. Python has much better tools for parsing HTML (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or strings (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in general.

```
def getTag(htmlList):
    tagList=[]
    for iterate, character in enumerate(htmlList):
        tagAppend = ''
        if character=='<':
            for index, word in enumerate(htmlList):
                if index>iterate:
                    # use word here otherwise this will never be True
                    if word=='>':
                        tagList.append(tagAppend)
                        break
                    # and here
                    tagAppend += word

    return tagList
```

The key bug is the use of character instead of word. I think it will work fine otherwise. Although it is inefficient.

We can also simplify. No need for nested for loops.

```
def getTag(htmlList):
    tagList=[]
    tag = ""
    for character in htmlList:
        if character == "<":
            tag = ""
        elif character == ">":
            tagList.append(tag)
        else:
            tag.append(character)

    return tagList
```

The above has some serious issues depending on what constraints are on the input data. It might be instructive to think through it and see if you can find them.

We can also use built-ins like split and join to great affect as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think `re` would be a good choice.

```
def get_tag(l):
    return re.findall(r'<([a-z]+)>', ''.join(l))

get_tag(l)
['html', 'head', 'meta']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is **nearly correct**, you only need to replace all appearance of `character` in the inner loop with `word`; `word` was never used in that inner loop:

```
        ...
        for index, word in enumerate(htmlList):
            if index > iterate:
                if word == '>':   # here
                    tagList.append(tagAppend)
                    break
                tagAppend += word # here
        ...
```

---

You could do without `enumerate` and a nested for loop with the following:

```
def get_tag(htmlList):
    tag_list = []
    for x in htmlList:
        if x == '<':
            tag = ''
            continue
        elif x == '>':
            tag_list.append(tag)
            continue
        tag += x
    return tag_list
```